# MySQL SELECT records NOT EXISTS from specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**USERS**

```
1. id
2. name
3. surname
4. email
```

**TICKETS**

```
1. id
2. id_user
3. film
4. date_selling
```

I would like to list all the users haven't bought a ticket since a specific date.

I've tried with a lot of combinations, but I can't find the right way to reach the result.

Query 1:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN tickets t ON t.id_user = u.id
WHERE t.date_selling >= "2019-01-01" 
GROUP BY u.id HAVING COUNT(t.id) = 0;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 
FROM tickets t 
WHERE t.id_user = u.id AND t.date_selling >= "2019-01-01"));
```

Comment: *I can't find the right way to reach the result.* ... please describe the undesired results or errors of these queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM tickets t 
  WHERE t.id_user = u.id AND t.date_selling >= '2019-01-01'
);
```

or with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN tickets t 
ON t.id_user = u.id AND t.date_selling >= '2019-01-01' 
WHERE t.id_user IS NULL;
```

Comment: It's what I did in my second try

Comment: No it's not. You use ON instead of WHERE

Comment: @DamianoFontana - This is the correct answer, yes. This should work.

Comment: @DamianoFontana did you edit your code with WHERE instead of ON? If this is the code that you originally used then it should work. Or it isn't?